# How to sort an array by a string attribute in a predefined order

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array of reviews. Each review has an attribute of connotation (string) of either positive, negative, or neutral.

I'm trying to build a `sort` method that will put all the negatives in the beginning, then the neutrals and then the positives. Also, another method that do the other way around.

I tried the following:

```
res.sort! { |re1,re2|
  case
  when re1.connotation == re2.connotation
    0
  when re1.connotation == "positive"
    -1
  when re1.connotation == "negative"
    1
  else
    0
  end
}
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Some sample data would be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to bother with those spaceship operator values (-1, 0, 1)

```
order = ['negative', 'neutral', 'positive']

data.sort_by {|d| order.index(d.connotation)}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
connotations = {"positive" => 1, "negative" => -1, "neutral" => 0}
res.sort_by { |re| conotations[re.connotation] }
```

Comment: If the words used to designate ratings might change, to improve maintainability perhaps `RATINGS = { high: "positive", middle: "neutral", low: "negative" }; connotations = { RATINGS[:high]=>1, RATINGS[:middle]=>0, RATINGS[:low]=>-1}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Review
  attr_reader :name, :connotation
  def initialize(name, connotation)
    @name = name
    @connotation = connotation
  end
end

data = [Review.new("BMW 335i",        "positive"),
        Review.new("Honda CRV",       "neutral"),
        Review.new("Porsche Boxster", "positive"),
        Review.new("Pontiac Aztec",   "negative")]

data.sort_by(&:connotation)
  #=> [#<Review:0x007fa3e483f510 @name="Pontiac Aztec",@connotation="negative">,
  #    #<Review:0x007fa3e483f678 @name="Honda CRV", @connotation="neutral">,
  #    #<Review:0x007fa3e483f5d8 @name="Porsche Boxster", @connotation="positive">,
  #    #<Review:0x007fa3e483f6f0 @name="BMW 335i", @connotation="positive">]
```

If the ratings were "bad", "OK" and "good", it would be back to the drawing board.